# Dynamic interception of calls in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, dynamic

I am curious to learn if .NET supports any form of dynamic interception of method calls (or properties invocations) at runtime. That is, can you intercept a call to an object without static compilation information such as an interface (along the lines of the CORBA DII ([link text](http://www.puder.org/corba/cg/)) or COM's IDispatch).

If not, would the new 'Dynamically Typed Objects' feature in C# 4.0 help in this regard.

Comment: Strongly related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c

Comment: Is it strongly related? I have no class that I may add attributes to.

Comment: I'm currently investigating the 'RealProxy' and the 'Profile Injection Application Block'.

Comment: Actually, I meant 'Castle Dynamic Proxy' (not 'RealProxy') as that looks, so far, to be what I'm looking for.

Comment: @karma, the same underlying mechanisms used for AOP in .net tend to be used for method interception ...

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There is nothing built-in that allows you to intercept an object that you can not control instantiation of. Similarly, there will be no new facilities for this in the upcoming .net 4.0.

If you can control instantiation:

1. If your object can be MarshalByRef you can use [RealProxy](https://gist.github.com/SamSaffron/2823021).
2. You could use quite a few IOC containers, eg. [LinFu](https://code.google.com/archive/p/linfu), [Castle Dynamic Proxy](https://www.castleproject.org/projects/dynamicproxy/)
3. You could use a tool like [PostSharp](https://www.postsharp.net/), [Mono Cecil](https://www.mono-project.com/Cecil/) or [Microsoft CCI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1380380/microsoft-cci-resources-references-for-writing-compilers) to rewrite your assemblies with the interceptions as a post compile step.

If you can not control instantiation

1. You can use [ICorDebug](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/) - the .Net debugging APIs which are really hard to use and heavy.
2. You can use [ICorProfiler](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/jmstall/) - the .Net profiling APIs where are also pretty complicated to use.

Alternatively, you could look at a dynamic language like IronRuby, which has a built-in `alias_method` and `define_method` goodness (which allows you to redefine anything), so interception baked in.

---

In .NET 4.5, the aforementioned `ICorProfiler` is introducing a method to [ReJIT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/davbr/rejit-for-realz) methods which provides another hook for method interception (provided you are not running a concurrent/bg GC and the method is not inlined).

Comment: You can use RealProxy if you're going through an interface, as well.

Comment: I think 'Castle Dynamic Proxy' seems to best fit what I'm looking for.  It's API is nice and simple.

Comment: Good stuff. One thing to add - Mono.Cecil has some overlaps with PostSharp.