# C# hook into method start and finish

Tags: c#

This might have been answered here before and I'm just not searching for the right thing. If so I apologize.

What I'd like to do is to automatically execute a method when any method of a class gets called and finishes executing.

Any idea how i could accomplish this? I looked into Reflection, but not sure if that would work out.

Any help appreciated :-)

Comment: I answered this quite throughly here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331851/dynamic-interception-of-calls-in-net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are in a position to / it makes sense to do something in your compile process, PostSharp or Mono.Cecil are good tools for doing AOP at build time.

Otherwise [go +1 Sam's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1331851/dynamic-interception-of-calls-in-net)

Answer (score 1):

You can use Aspect Oriented Programming framework, like PostSharp.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a callback.

```
void SomeMethod ( delegate MyDelegate )
{

// do some things

MyDelegate(); // execute method referenced by delegate 
}
```

Your method you want to automatically execute when SomeMethod finishes you pass through a delegate in SomeMethod.

Comment: Or partial methods. But he wants it for all methods. This would get tedious