# Java like Agent in C#: Augument Classes?

Tags: java, c#

Being new to C#'s advanced functionality and VM, I ask myself if C# does provide a similar mechanism like the JVM's agent functionality of inspecting, modifying and potentially replacing C# classes?

Comment: Instead of tinkering with your code after the fact, make your code more composable from the ground up. That way you don't need any "augmentation" to be hacked together in any way.

Comment: There are many things need to be done exactly this way.

Answer (score 0):

It can be done at a low level through the use of IL. Please see this answer for details and a possible alternative:

[Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method)

Comment: Are there any libraries easying the pain like an equivalent of cglib / jasm or javasist?