# How to replace the pointer to the overridden (virtual) method in the pointer of my method? (Release x64 and x86)

Tags: c#

In question
[Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method)
I found a good response from @ Logman. I do not have standing to ask it in the comments.

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

namespace ReplaceHandles
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Injection.replace();
            Target target = new Target();
            target.test();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }

    public class Injection
    {
        public static void replace()
        {
            MethodInfo methodToReplace = typeof(Target).GetMethod("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            MethodInfo methodToInject = typeof(Target2).GetMethod("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToReplace.MethodHandle);
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToInject.MethodHandle);
            ReplaceInner(methodToReplace, methodToInject);
        }

        static void ReplaceInner(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    int* inj = (int*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
                    int* tar = (int*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
                    *tar = *inj;
                }
                else
                {
                    ulong* inj = (ulong*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
                    ulong* tar = (ulong*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
                    *tar = *inj;
                }
            }
        }
    }


    public class Base
    {
        public virtual void test()
        {

        }
    }

    public class Target : Base
    {
        public override void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target.test()");
        }

        public void test3()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target.test3()");
        }
    }

    public class Target2
    {
        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target.test2()");
        }
    }
}
```

Everything works, but does not work the replacement of overridden methods.

Comment: ```if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    int* inj = (int*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;``` ... do you happen to have any resources as to why it's `+2`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Updated Answer

First of all, keep in mind that

> Method Address = Method Virtual Address + base address of class that [declares](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.memberinfo.declaringtype(v=vs.110).aspx) this member..

If the method to replace is a **virtual** overridden method, please use the following.

```
if (methodToReplace.IsVirtual)
{
    ReplaceVirtualInner(methodToReplace, methodToInject);
} else {
    ReplaceInner(methodToReplace, methodToInject);
}
```

Tested with **both** platform target **x86** and **x64**: it **works**!!!.

```
static void ReplaceVirtualInner(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
{
    unsafe
    {
        UInt64* methodDesc = (UInt64*)(methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer());
        int index = (int)(((*methodDesc) >> 32) & 0xFF);
        if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
        {
            uint* classStart = (uint*)methodToReplace.DeclaringType.TypeHandle.Value.ToPointer();
            classStart += 10;
            classStart = (uint*)*classStart;
            uint* tar = classStart + index;

            uint* inj = (uint*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
            //int* tar = (int*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
            *tar = *inj;
        }
        else
        {
            ulong* classStart = (ulong*)methodToReplace.DeclaringType.TypeHandle.Value.ToPointer();
            classStart += 8;
            classStart = (ulong*)*classStart;
            ulong* tar = classStart + index;

            ulong* inj = (ulong*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
            //ulong* tar = (ulong*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
            *tar = *inj;
        }
    }
}
```

### Original Answer

You have to run (from a `cmd` sell) the `exe` compiled in `Release` mode, not in `Debug`.

I've tried and I confirm it does not throw exceptions in that case.

```
C:\dev\Calc>C:\dev\Calc\bin\Release\Calc.exe
Target.targetMethod1()
Target.targetMethod2()
Not injected 2
Target.targetMethod3(Test)
Target.targetMethod4()

Version x64 Release


Version x64 Release


Version x64 Release


Version x64 Release

Injection.injectionMethod1
Injection.injectionMethod2
Injected 2
Injection.injectionMethod3 Test
```

as you can see, the above runs whithout the following exception

```
C:\dev\Calc>C:\dev\Calc\bin\Debug\Calc.exe
Target.targetMethod1()
Target.targetMethod2()
Not injected 2
Target.targetMethod3(Test)
Target.targetMethod4()

Version x64 Debug


Version x64 Debug


Version x64 Debug


Version x64 Debug


Unhandled Exception: System.AccessViolationException: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.
   at InjectionTest.Target.targetMethod1() in C:\dev\Calc\Program.cs:line 38
   at InjectionTest.Target.test() in C:\dev\Calc\Program.cs:line 31
   at InjectionTest.Program.Main(String[] args) in C:\dev\Calc\Program.cs:line 21
```

and the **reason** is explained in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method#comment64907608_36415711) comment

> in debug compiler adds some middle man code and to inject your method
>   you need to recalculate address of your method

### After the question's edit

Looking at the revised question, I confirm that there is an issue if the `Base` method is declared as `virtual`. I'm trying to find a workaround.

### workaround 1

My first idea was to replace the `new` keyworkd instead of the `override` (so when the Base method is not `virtual`).
That makes it **work**, so I guess that (when we have a virtual method) the injection shoud happen at the base class level maybe... and the different behaviour must have to do with using `callvirt` vs `call`

Comment: Yes, there are no errors. In the example of the lack overridden method. The code is taken from the original response. In my code, I added a base class "Base" with a virtual method targetMethod1(). In a derived class "Target", I override this method. In this case, it does not work. There are no errors, but does not work

Comment: sorry, I'm not not sure to understand: are you running the debug or the release exe and also pls clarify what is your expected result. Thanks a lot. In the meantime I can add a comment pointing here for you

Comment: Also, I suggest you should edit your question and show your *full* code.

Comment: Sorry, I had to immediately do so. Example corrected. I work in release.

Comment: @Евгений Look at the updated answer, test it yourself and if it's ok pls mark this as **answer**, thanks! ))

Comment: Taking a step back, what is it you are trying to do?

Comment: @brumScouse Hi! :-) What I *have* done (I'm not *trying* any longer) is taking a code that was working for normal methods and extend it also to the case of virtual/override methods, i.e. I've answered the question. In particular the program is a method replacer that injects a new function into a target... Hope I've clarified the matter... It was difficult cause this is not documented ;)

Comment: @Machine Learning, I have an error "An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occurred in ReplaceHandles.exe".
In this line,

    * tar = * inj;

Why?
I ran in the Release x86 and x64. In both cases, such an error.

Comment: I'm in configuration Releaase, Platform Target Any Cpu or x86 (I see an exception if I set platform target to x64)

Comment: Mystic. The code is identical.
Launched in Release Any Cpu - works,
then launched x86 - works too,
x64 - an error.

Comment: ...but so, that's a marginal issue. Basically this answers your question :) either you edit your question again (but I don't think it's so important) or I honestly think this should be marked as answer. Anyway I'm on mobile, I can't add much more...

Comment: Response halfway. I am pleased to note your answer, if it is complete.

Comment: If this answer works as expected for x86 and the **only** missing thing is to make it work also for x64, please edit your question and specify it: I will complete the answer **later**

Comment: I edited the question. I think that by default, the code should work as x64 and x86.

Comment: @Евгений it was `classStart += 8;` for x64. now please double check, let me know and finally note this as answer thanks

Comment: @Machine Learning, thank you very much, you really helped me! Sorry I do not have 15 reputation to enhance the reputation of the answer.

Comment: Great work you done here. I will try to see if I can add debug mode but for now I don't understand one thing. Is delta you add to classStart (`classStart += 8; //10;`) fixed or can change for some reason?

Comment: @Logman Thanks, it's very kind of you! I add a fixed delta of 10 for x86 and a delta of 8 instead for x64: it's not well documented *afaik*, I found the latter *experimentally* :)

Comment: Hi @Machine Learning! Maybe look at my problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39034018/how-to-replace-a-pointer-to-a-pointer-to-a-method-in-a-class-of-my-method-inheri