# How to replace a pointer to a pointer to a method in a class of my method inherited from the system class?

Tags: c#

Already asked this question. 
[How to replace the pointer to the overridden (virtual) method in the pointer of my method? (Release x64 and x86)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38782934/how-to-replace-the-pointer-to-the-overridden-virtual-method-in-the-pointer-of)
Thanks @Machine Learning, solved the problem. But a new problem arose. If the system inherited from the class, such as "Systems.Windows.Forms", then the change does not work.
Example:

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace ReplaceHandles
{
    public class Target1 : UserControl
    {
        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target1.test()");
        }
    }

    public class Target2
    {
        public void test()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Target2.test()");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Injection.Replace();
            var target = new Target1();
            target.test();
            Console.Read();
        }
    }
}
```

Class that replaces pointers

```
    public class Injection
    {
        public static void Replace()
        {
            var methodToReplace = typeof(Target1).GetMethod("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            var methodToInject = typeof(Target2).GetMethod("test", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public);
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToReplace.MethodHandle);
            RuntimeHelpers.PrepareMethod(methodToInject.MethodHandle);
            if (methodToReplace.IsVirtual) ReplaceVirtualInner(methodToReplace, methodToInject);
            else ReplaceInner(methodToReplace, methodToInject);
        }
```

Replacing the virtual methods

```
        static void ReplaceVirtualInner(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                var methodDesc = (UInt64*)(methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer());
                var index = (int)(((*methodDesc) >> 32) & 0xFF);
                if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    if (methodToReplace.DeclaringType != null)
                    {
                        var classStart = (uint*)methodToReplace.DeclaringType.TypeHandle.Value.ToPointer();
                        classStart += 10;
                        classStart = (uint*)*classStart;
                        var tar = classStart + index;

                        var inj = (uint*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
#if DEBUG

                        var injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                        var tarInst = (byte*)*tar;
                        var injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                        var tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);
                        *tarSrc = (((int)injInst + 5) + *injSrc) - ((int)tarInst + 5);
#else
                        *tar = *inj;
#endif
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (methodToReplace.DeclaringType != null)
                    {
                        var classStart = (ulong*)methodToReplace.DeclaringType.TypeHandle.Value.ToPointer();
                        classStart += 8;
                        classStart = (ulong*)*classStart;
                        var tar = classStart + index;

                        var inj = (ulong*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
#if DEBUG
                        var injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                        var tarInst = (byte*)*tar;
                        var injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                        var tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);
                        *tarSrc = (((int)injInst + 5) + *injSrc) - ((int)tarInst + 5);
#else
                        *tar = *inj;
#endif
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

and replacing not virtual methods

```
        static void ReplaceInner(MethodInfo methodToReplace, MethodInfo methodToInject)
        {
            unsafe
            {
                if (IntPtr.Size == 4)
                {
                    var inj = (int*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
                    var tar = (int*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 2;
#if DEBUG
                    var injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                    var tarInst = (byte*)*tar;
                    var injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                    var tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);

                    *tarSrc = (((int)injInst + 5) + *injSrc) - ((int)tarInst + 5);
#else
                    *tar = *inj;
#endif
                }
                else
                {
                    ulong* inj = (ulong*)methodToInject.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
                    ulong* tar = (ulong*)methodToReplace.MethodHandle.Value.ToPointer() + 1;
#if DEBUG
                    var injInst = (byte*)*inj;
                    var tarInst = (byte*)*tar;
                    var injSrc = (int*)(injInst + 1);
                    var tarSrc = (int*)(tarInst + 1);

                    *tarSrc = (((int)injInst + 5) + *injSrc) - ((int)tarInst + 5);
#else
                    *tar = *inj;
#endif
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Only one question comes to my mind when I read this: Why?

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar reverse engineering and similar techniques? ... Anyway, I'm curious :) and will try soon...

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar, Hard to say no to native language. Please treat with understanding. It is very necessary for the profiling of large software. To quickly place the performance counters. And so that no traces of the following runs.

Comment: If the *replacement* class is a UserControl you need to replace `= *inj;` with `= methodToInject.MethodHandle.GetFunctionPointer().ToInt32();` This is sure and tested. Now, when the *target* is a UserControl, the problem is again that the `GetFunctionPointer` returns the correct address, but it's unclear to me how to find its pointer. I guess this is due to the fact that winforms derive from MarshalByRefObject and so I'm not even sure that an injection can be done in managed code...

Comment: Does not work with `[assembly: System.Diagnostics.Debuggable(true, true)]` set in AssemblyInfo.cs

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When the target class is derived from `MarshalByRefObject`, then the `ReplaceInner` (for normal methods) stops working but `ReplaceVirtualInner` (for `overridden` methods) is ok.

> MarshalByRefObject is the base class for objects that communicate
>   across application domain boundaries by exchanging messages using a
>   proxy. Objects that do not inherit from MarshalByRefObject are
>   implicitly marshal by value. When a remote application references a
>   marshal by value object, a copy of the object is passed across
>   application domain boundaries.

This could be partially fixed by marking as `virtual` the method to replace.

But when the target class is derived from `Content` also the `ReplaceVirtualInner` (for `overridden` methods) stops working.

**Unfortunately `Windows.Forms` are derived from both of them, so I don't see an easy work-around.**

### Different approaches and alternatives

You may want to consider a different approach: a basic example of [tracing with PostSharp and Aspect-Oriented Programming](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/saveenr/2008/11/20/caop-elegant-tracing-with-postsharp-and-aspect-oriented-programming/), a CodeProject [article](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/337564/Aspect-Oriented-Programming-Using-Csharp-and-PostS) and the [doc](http://doc.postsharp.net/example-trace) about tracing.

Furthermore, another alternative (don't know if possible for you) is to use the `UserControl` of **WPF instead of Forms** and in that case the *normal* method replacement would *work fine* (after you've imported the needed assemblies and made the Main `[STAThread]`)

### Final solution with Reverse Engineering

Ok, if you really want to make it work *at any cost*, let's proceed with reversing the target.

Open your compiled .exe with [CFF Explorer](http://www.ntcore.com/exsuite.php).

Locate the tables under [.Net Directory](http://www.ntcore.com/files/dotnetformat.htm#NETDir)`> MetaData Streams` and ungroup the `Method Tables`.
You will find the 2 methods with the same name and different `RVA` corresponding to the 2 classes (`TypeDef`). 
You simply have to ovverride the target `RVA` with the injection method `RVA` and save the reversed exe with a new name.

Comment: I've edited my answer to include a solution by reverse engineering, in case the other alternatives were not immediately viable for you.