# How do you send NumPad keys using SendKeys?

Tags: c#, winforms, sendkeys, keystroke, numpad

**I want to send the keystroke of NumPad keys (1-9).**

I tried to use:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{NUMPAD1}");
```

but it says

> System.ArgumentException: The keyword NUMPAD1 is invalid *(translated)*

So i don't know the right keycode for the NumPad.

Comment: Reading [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.sendkeys.aspx), it looks like it is not possible...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Out of curiosity I looked at the [source code](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Windows.Forms/winforms/Managed/System/WinForms/SendKeys.cs) for SendKeys. There's nothing explaining why the numpad codes were excluded. I wouldn't recommend this as a preferred option, but it's possible to add the missing codes to the class using reflection:

```
FieldInfo info = typeof(SendKeys).GetField("keywords",
    BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
Array oldKeys = (Array)info.GetValue(null);
Type elementType = oldKeys.GetType().GetElementType();
Array newKeys = Array.CreateInstance(elementType, oldKeys.Length + 10);
Array.Copy(oldKeys, newKeys, oldKeys.Length);
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    var newItem = Activator.CreateInstance(elementType, "NUM" + i, (int)Keys.NumPad0 + i);
    newKeys.SetValue(newItem, oldKeys.Length + i);
}
info.SetValue(null, newKeys);
```

Now I can use eg. `SendKeys.Send("{NUM3}")`. It doesn't seem to work for sending alt codes however, so maybe that's why they left them out.

Comment: How do you add to the source code using reflection?

Comment: @Bedir If you mean adding to/replacing an existing .NET method that can't be overridden with inheritance, I'm not sure. The answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method) may help you.

Comment: Can confirm, for using alt codes, this does unfortunately not work.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to pass in a number in the same manner as passing in a letter.  For example:

```
SendKeys.SendWait("{A}");  //sends the letter 'A'
SendKeys.SendWait("{5}");  //sends the number '5'
```

Comment: I know, thats basic stuff. I wanted the NumPad Keys, not the normal numbers.

Comment: of course there is a diffrence, in nearly every game control configs you can use the numpad for control, and the numpad keyy have their own names (like NUM_4), displayed in the settings when pressed. This has no effect on the numbers on top of the keyboard.

Comment: They do appear to map to the same char code though. 
            ConsoleKeyInfo c1 = Console.ReadKey(true);

            Console.WriteLine(c1.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(c1.KeyChar);
            Console.WriteLine((int)c1.KeyChar);

            ConsoleKeyInfo c2 = Console.ReadKey(true);
            
            Console.WriteLine(c2.Key);
            Console.WriteLine(c2.KeyChar);
            Console.WriteLine((int)c2.KeyChar);
if this is any help, it does look possible via the windows API http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?347527-Using-SendKeys-to-Send-Number-Pad-Numbers

Comment: Great help, this helps me alot.