# Swap method bodies at runtime in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, reflection

I want to modify a method of UnityEngine.dll at runtime. How can i do it?

Comment: Reflection is hard and so far possible mostly not a good approach in Unity. What is the intended purpose? You might be running in an xy-problem.

Comment: most probably your problem can be solved using delegates. just create a public `Action` of `Func` and assign it. when you want to change what it does, just assign something else.

Comment: whatever you are trying to achieve here is probably barking at the wrong tree

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method)