# Can I change a function/method definition in C#? (redefine, not override)

Tags: c#

Is there a way to redefine a function definition/method in C#?

**Situation:**

Modding someone else's code, and they have:

```
namespace TheirCode 
{
  public static class SomeUtility
  {
    public static void A(this Thing thing) 
    {
      //do something I want to change
    }
  }
}
```

I can load another dll that will allow me to insert my own code...but I want to change the behavior of `a_thing.A();`  I need the changes to affect all `Thing`s, not just any derived `NewThing`s I might create.

Can I rewrite the method definition somehow?  Can I change the behavior another way?

Thanks

Comment: You're not clear about whether `A()` is static or not. It matters a little. And is their assembly signed?  Open source?

Comment: Short answer: No.  Not without decompiling and recompiling.

Comment: Here recompiling would involve replacing the author's .dll with my own .dll, instead of just creating my own additional .dll to be loaded?

Comment: Yes. And when it's signed you better have control over all dependent pieces.

Comment: Loks to be possible, but looks noz to be simple at all: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37549/CLR-Injection-Runtime-Method-Replacer

Comment: Look in to the terminology "code weaving" and the library `Mono.Cecil`, that may help you get started.

Answer (score 0):

Oh wow, there's a whole series of answers in this other question:

[Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method/42043003#42043003)

The Harmony answer looks great!

I don't know why I couldn't find it earlier when I was searching; maybe this question's search terms will help someone else.