# Is there a way to catch a method call without subscribing it to any sort of Events?

Tags: c#, events

suppose we have this scenario :

a class that you are not allowed to modify anything in it :

```
 public class ForbiddenClass_A
    {

        public void TheMethod()
        {
            //do stuff
        }
    }
```

and another read only class that calls a method from the previous class:

```
public class ForbiddenClass_B
{
    ForbiddenClass_A fc_a;

    void Update()
    {
        //some logic that if true it will call :
        fc_a.TheMethod();
    }
}
```

Now you have your class, that you do anything to it, and from it you want to know if **TheMethod()** :

```
public class MyClass
{
    //call this when TheMethod() from ForbiddenClass_A is called.
    public void TheMethod_Catcher()
    {

    }
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: There are various ways of detecting the caller and then you can have `public void TheMethod()  { TheMethod_Catcher(...caller...); //do stuff }; }` - but what would concern me is the idea of a 'forbidden class'. If it can't be changed, don't let it be changed. This sounds like an X-Y problem, what exactly are you trying to prevent? And what are you intending to actually do in `TheMethod_Catcher()`?

Comment: I think, you should mark them 'internal' then they can only called from your code.

Comment: @PoulBak internal isn't a guarantee of that. Private methods can be called by reflection, after all.

Comment: You're right, there's no guarantee, but they would be hidden from IntelliSense and couldn't be found without reflection.

Comment: @stuartd the "forbidden_class" is a bought asset (unity) and i don't want to modify them, if that's the ultimate solution, sure i'll just add an event subscription there, but i wanna know if there is another solution first. thanks :)

Comment: @PoulBak could you please elaborate a little bit ? reflection kept popping up in all the results i found before posting this, but couldn't really found an exact solution, thanks

Comment: Well, as @stuartd said, reflection can always be used to access even internal methods.

Comment: @PoulBak i think stuartd solution would still require accessing the "forbidden" class to at least subscribe to an event

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there a way to catch a method call without subscribing it to any
>   sort of Events?

Decoupled messaging is probably where you want to be, [event aggregator](https://martinfowler.com/eaaDev/EventAggregator.html) or any other pub sub method messaging system. Although you still have to subscribe to something, the participants need not know about each other allowing you to make the methods private.

*Unity*, *MvvmLight* both have these sorts of messaging systems, however they are truly dime-a-dozen, there are plenty

**Example of how this might work**

```
public CreateUserForm()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    EventPublisher.Instance.Subscribe<NewUserCreated>
        (n => listBoxUsers.Items.Add(n.User.Name));
}

...

// some other class
private void Update()
{

    var user = new User()
               {
                   Name = textBoxUserName.Text,
                   Password = textBoxPassword.Text,
                   Email = textBoxEmail.Text
               };
    EventPublisher.Instance.Publish(new NewUserRequested(user));
}
```

**Update**

There are injection techniques if you are interest for .net

[Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method)

Comment: you said "Although you still have to subscribe to something", this mean that those "forbidden classes" still need to be modified right ?

Comment: @alaslipknot indeed yes, in regards to release mode,  unless you use some sort of Injection (which will be exceedingly hard), i doubt you can do this without modifying the target classes