# C# Inject code into external method at runtime using AOP

Tags: c#, methods, code-injection, methodinfo, method-interception

I want to inject code into a external method, without editing the source code.
I can already replace the current method to reference to my own method, because of [Dynamically replace the contents of a C# method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method).

I still need to able to modify a external method body at runtime, which means to be able to inject code before the method call and after the method call.

I **can't** **manually** call this method i want to modify. is a service that runs itself.

I have tried:

1. Reflection.Emit -> but this creates a new method which is not referenced.
2. Marshall -> `Marshal.GetFunctionPointerForDelegate`, and then replace the method to after that call the marshalled function -> does not work as the replace is a pointer and the marhal changes the pointer.

Situation:

```cs
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var oldMethod = typeof(InstanceClassA).GetMethod("OldMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);
            var beforeMethod = typeof(InstanceClassA).GetMethod("BeforeMethod", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public);

            oldMethod.Before(() => Console.WriteLine("Called Before"));
            oldMethod.Before(() => beforeMethod);

            //This is *TESTING* only as I can't manually call the method i want to inject.

            var instance = new InstanceClassA();
            //Should now call the beforeMethod and the called before
            instance.OldMethod("With Before");
            //Should call the after method

            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    public static class MethodInfoUtils
    {
        //Will *NOT* allow return values as this should return oldMethod return value
        //Will allow Actions and another MethodInfo
        public static void Before(this MethodInfo method)
        {
            // Code to inject code before calling the external method
        }

        //Will *NOT* allow return values as this should return oldMethod return value
        //Will allow Actions and another MethodInfo
        public static void After(this MethodInfo method)
        {
            // Code to inject code after calling the external method
        }
    }

    public class InstanceClassA
    {
        public bool OldMethod(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(message);
            return true;
        }

        //message param is equal to the oldMethod param as it is called before the oldMethod is called
        public void BeforeMethod(string message)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("test");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you accomplish this by wrapping your existing class in a new one? That way you're not calling the method of the existing class while trying to change what that method does. You're just calling a method on the new class. What are the before and after things? That might shed light on what existing solutions are available, or on whether something much simpler like a wrapper class might be enough.

Comment: There are many variables to deal with before choosing an exact method for injecting code. First of all, C# is a managed language developed on top of the .NET framework. Are you sure the service you are targeting to inject is also built in the .NET framework? If not, it's still possible to inject code, but there may be plenty of extra hoops to jump through. That being said, there are already examples of other similar projects. Check out the open source project SharpNeedle for example: https://github.com/ChadSki/SharpNeedle

Comment: This is Aspect Weaving, and reminds me of PostSharp.

Comment: Well i would personally prefer to make it myself instead of using third party software. But if it is to much work, I will look into postSharp weaving or sharpneedle