# In C#, how do I add functionality to an already constructed class?

Tags: c#

Assume I already have a duck. Given that the Duck is readonly and C# is GC'd, is there any way to drop a duck into a mallard with inheritance without hitting a copy constructor?

```
public class Duck
{
    public readonly int wings;
    public Duck(int w)
    {
        wings = w;
    }
}

public class Mallard : Duck
{
    public Mallard(Duck a) : base(a.wings)
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: You can't "promote" an instance of one type to an instance of a derived type. `Duck` probably should be abstract, anyway.

Comment: "without hitting a copy constructor" You've only defined one constructor for the `Mallard` class. The only way to create a Mallard object is to run that constructor.

Comment: make the parent data for mallard be a duck, but not create a new duck.

Comment: `var duck = new Duck(3); duck = new Mallard(duck);` You really ought to specify which side the extra wing is on, though. That'll affect navigation. Also there's a chicken/egg issue.

Comment: "parent data" suggests composition. Now you're talking about the decorator pattern. But you can't avoid creating a new instance of *something*.

Comment: I assume under the hood the base object is just a ref though? Can you point it to the other instantiated object given that the base object in this case can never change?

Comment: what does "not create a new duck" mean? do you need to modify a certain instance of a Duck object to behave like a Mallard? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method

Comment: Are you trying to translate `static_cast<Mallard *>(duck)` (C++) to C#?

Comment: @madreflection Yeah

Comment: It would be unsafe to assume that the memory layout of `Mallard` is the same as `Duck`, even if *you* don't add any fields or virtual overrides to `Mallard`, so it's not possible.

Comment: @madreflection note that in C++ that's undefined behavior if `Duck` is not actually a `Mallard`, and even if you don't hit anything sensitive, the polymorphic behavior of the `Mallard` will still be as a `Duck`, because you're not changing the vtable of the instance

Comment: @artcorpse: I'm quite aware of that. It doesn't change the fact that *the OP* is trying to do it.

Comment: @Carbon It might help to understand why you need such a static_cast, as it doesn't seem to accomplish much. If you need to operate with methods from type `Mallard` on a `Duck` something like this might work: https://blog.tchatzigiannakis.com/changing-an-objects-type-at-runtime-in-c-sharp/.

Comment: More importantly, will your design also need to convert the river to whiskey?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `Duck` is not a `Mallard`, and in C# there's no way to make it be one.  You're going to have to construct a new `Mallard` in some way, whether that's by a copy constructor or other method.

In some cases, you may be able to go with composition over inheritance (although I don't think it models your domain in this example).

```
public class Mallard
{
   public readonly Duck duck;
   public Mallard(Duck d)
   {
      duck = d;
   }
}
```

If you're just looking to add new functionality to a Duck, but can't change it, you can use extension methods.

```
public static class DuckExtensions
{
   public IEnumerable<Wing> CookWings(this Duck duck) { ... }
}
```