# How to count function calls for unittesting?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, reflection

I use my own small C# unittesting framework to test my code.

Sometimes I need the functionality to count how often a function of a fake object is called. Like this:

```
IDatabase fakeDb = new FakeDatabase();
IResult result = new Foo().ToTest(fakeDb);

//Some other tests

UTest.Equal(fakeDb.FakeCloseCalled(), 1);
```

So at the moment my FakeDatabase-class looks like this:

```
class FakeDatabase : IDatabase
{
    //All the other code

    public int FakeCloseCalled
    {
        get;
        private set;
    }

    public void Close()
    {
        FakeCloseCalled++;
    }
}
```

So, everytime I want to know how often a function of my fake objects was called I have to create a property for this in my FakeClass.

So I wonder if there is a more "generic" way to do this. e.g. profilers and some unittest-frameworks seem to be able to count the calls to functions.

So is there a more generic way to count the calls to Close without creating a property every time?

Answer (score 1):

You could use reflection to instantiate an instance of the IDatabase, and replace the objects methods with code that tracks thet calls using various methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42043003/1928310):

I believe this is how [Moq](https://github.com/moq/moq4) does it. Only reinvent when you want to learn.