# Is it possible to hijack a call to a C# method to execute another piece of code first?

Tags: c#, appium

#### Background

I'm building an automation framework (just a bunch of C# classes/interfaces) to drive a desktop application using Appium and WinAppDriver. One of the awesome features offered by Appium/WinAppDriver is the ability to take a screenshot of the running application at any time. I want to easily toggle on/off screenshot capture upon every method call of my automation framework without altering every method of my automation framework because that is effort and a lot of code duplication and also pretty boring.

#### Ideal solution

I'd like to use the magic that is reflection (or a third party library if one exists) to write a piece of code that says `before executing any method on this object, execute this other piece of code`. Is this even possible?

Comment: While you can [replace a method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7299097/dynamically-replace-the-contents-of-a-c-sharp-method), it might be better to see if you can automatically create a proxy object, in the way that `ImpromptuInterface`  does, for example.

Comment: Anything is possible with aspect-oriented programming.

Comment: You can probably do that with [Fody](https://github.com/Fody/Fody) or source generators if the APIs you are using support .NET 5. Though I'm not sure either would be better than altering your design to support it.

Comment: Omigosh, the Harmony library is amazing and absolutely does what I want it to! https://github.com/pardeike/Harmony
Thanks everyone for pointing me to the other stack overflow question/answer