# How to instrument code for logging C#

Tags: c#, logging

I'm wondering if there's any way of having some sort of Aspect-Oriented way of setting up logging of C# code. Or if the code could be instrumented for automatic logging.

At the moment the code is riddled with `Log("Enter method XXX")` and `Log("Leaving method XXX")` which make maintenance really tedious.

Ideally I'd like to have something that does the logging automatically the same way as the libraries are instrumented for profiling.

The next best thing would be to have some custom attributes maybe that I can tag my methods with. These would put some logging code on entrance and exit of the method.

And if the solution were compatible with the EntLib that would be perfect :)

Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the Enterprise Library, you have everything you need.  Take a look at this article: http://www.codewrecks.com/blog/index.php/2009/01/31/unity-and-aop-in-enterprise-library/

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to have to refactor my code to use Unity then :/

Answer (score 1):

You could use [Log4PostSharp](http://code.google.com/p/postsharp-user-plugins/wiki/Log4PostSharp). I am not sure though what the future of this looks like as PostSharp went commercial.

Answer (score 0):

What your referring too is a cross cutting concern, and not only affects your application but other applications that you might install at your establishment. The Enterprise Blocks are great and the inversion of control principal does help a lot with extracting repeating code from out of the system. However there is no way of logging without deciding some place in your code that you wish to record the event. for example exceptions, logging in, logging out, db actions, restricted actions etc. If you go the Enterrpise route its all done through configuration files and policies.

In the solutions I have provided, I have moved the logging functionality outside of the application space and it now sits aside every piece of code that I develop, ready and waiting to do the logging for me. On the last project I used a combination of Enterprise Blocks and Couchdb. Couchdb really helps with the aspect side as it works using REST and Json without involving itself too much in your application writing an interface to the log files is just a matter of a bit of HTML, it really is a fire and forget type affair, until that bad ol day when you need to scour the logs :)

The only problem that I have seen in applications where you automate the logging is that you use some sort of delegate process and pass things into them, which increases stack space. But this is so trivial that its beyond reason.

Program to interfaces and defined interfaces and you should be okay.

Answer (score 0):

I remember something regarding Interceptors / Proxying to log entry/exit of methods.

Stack Overflow question - [How do I intercept a method call in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c)
and check out this blog (ref'd in the same question) - http://madcoderspeak.blogspot.com/2005/09/essential-interception-using-contexts.html