# How to listen an abstract method?

Tags: c#, events, abstract-class

In my abstract class can I listen an abstract method and fire an event whenever that method is called? If yes how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really as an abstract method is always overidden and there is no guarantee that the override call `base.Method()` to an implementation of it.

Your best bet is to create a virtual method which raises the event and then make all your overrides call `base.Method()`

If you want to intercept the method call, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c) is a question about how to do that.

Answer (score 3):

Abstract or no, you're looking for an Inversion of Control (IoC) framework here, specifically one that lets you do method interception.

I'd look at [Unity](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff648512.aspx), or [Spring](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spring_Framework). There are a few others out there.

Answer (score 3):

The best way to do this is as follows:

```
public abstract class MyClass {

    public void DoOuter() {
        FireEvent();
        DoInner();
    }

    protected abstract void DoInner();
}
```

When someone wants to call doInner they have to call `DoOuter()` in order to execute it. To specify functionality you override `DoInner()`. So `FireEvent()` is always called before whatever `DoInner()` functionality is specified... unless it gets called directly by a child class, which you can't really guard against.

Comment: This is actually a C# question, so I'm editing the answer a little, but the main idea is correct.

Comment: D'oh. Thanks, StriplingWarrior.