# Logger Method Design

Tags: c#, logging, api-design

I am writing a function in C# to log the actions of the users on our system and save them in a database.  Specifically I want to log certain functions of business logic as they are called. I came about a logging method like this:

```
public static LogMethod(string user, string methodName, object[] parameters, string message)
```

Inside the method the proper `ToString()` function is called for each of the parameters.
For example for method Foo it is called like this:

```
void Foo(int a, SomeObject b)
{
     Logger.LogMethod(username, "Foo", new object[]{a,b}, "Beginning Foo");
     //etc
}
```

Is it a good way to log the function calls? What are the best practices to implement this purpose?
Would it affect performance in a bad way?

Comment: Could you just use the Microsoft [Logging Application Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff664569%28v=pandp.50%29.aspx)?

Comment: FYI - log4net has DB integration built in, might be useful : http://logging.apache.org/log4net/release/config-examples.html

Answer (score 3):

Yes, it affects performance because you have to use reflection to get the MethodInfo and then invoke it. Besides that, it kills maintainability because you cannot refactor the method names.

Have a look to the following previous Q&A for alternatives: [How do I intercept a method call in C#?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c)

Answer (score 3):

Don't litter your beautiful business logic with logging logic, which is a cross-cutting concern. You should employ a technique like method interception to intercept the methods that you want to log.

> Is it a good way to log the function calls?

No, it's not, frankly. Your code is now concerned with executing your business logic AND logging. That is code that is hard to write, hard to test, and very hard to maintain.

> What are the best practices to implement this purpose?

I encourage you to find a way to solve this problem that doesn't involve spoiling your code with logging code everywhere. The standard solution to this is to use something like method interception or aspect-oriented programming. There are many ways to achieve this (you can use one of many frameworks to set it up, but I'm partial to Castle Windsor).

> Would it affect performance in a bad way?

Only you can answer that question. If you're logging things like what a user is doing, unlikely. Users are slow and dumb, and they use things like disks and databases that are slow, and so aren't likely to care if you take an extra few milliseconds to log something. We aren't talking about critical loops here. **But only you can decide if it is unacceptably slow, and only you can measure your own application with and without the logging to see if it is unacceptably slow.**

Comment: Thanks a lot, At first I was considering tools like Spring, Unity, or Castle Windsor but learning them and combining them into my project could be too time consuming for my current project, your comment intrigued me to search more about AOP solutions, I finally stopped at PostSharp which looks like a good fit to my needs. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

As others have pointed out already, an AOP framework is probably the way to go.

---

If you still want to use your method, you can make a small improvement to it. If you put the parameters at the end, you can use the `params` keyword.

```
public static LogMethod(string user, string methodName, string message,
                        params object[] parameters)
```

This makes calling the method somewhat easier.

```
void Foo(int a, SomeObject b)
{
    Logger.LogMethod(username, "Foo", "Beginning Foo", a, b);
    //etc  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Everything affects performance, but whether the effect is "bad" is subjective. It also entirely depends on how often you call the method.

If you rearrage the arguments and use the `params` keyword, you can simplify the call:

```
public static LogMethod(string user, string methodName, string message, params object[] parameters)
```

Now your call is simpler:

```
Logger.LogMethod(username, "Foo", "Beginning Foo", a, b);
```

There is no need to declare the object array, the compiler will take care of this for you. See [params](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w5zay9db.aspx).

Also, you can further simplify calls by getting the calling method name from the stack:

```
public static LogMethod(string user, string message, params object[] parameters)
{
    string methodName = new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
    ...      
}
```

Now you don't need the methodName parameter. (In .Net 4.5, you can achieve the same thing with the [CallerMemberNameAttribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.callermembernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).)

With reflection you can go further; for instance you can get the names of the parameters passed to the calling method, the name of the class, etc.