# Track method input and input of methods of running dll using c#

Tags: c#

I have a need to record parameter values of methods been called with in application. A kind of log.
I don't want to touch the code of the running application dll, by adding a row in each method to log it.
Is there any way I can some kind mechanism to capture input/ouput paramert values, by inserting logger code into the dll without touching the main source code? i am trying to achive this in C#

Answer (score 0):

You will achieve this by using AOP. Refer [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8436/Intercepting-method-calls-in-C-an-approach-to-AOSD) link for more information.

Also have a look into this stackoverflow [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c).

Comment: Is there any way I can do this without injecting any code into the dll? Kind of profiler?