# Logging of each working method as default in log4net?

Tags: c#, log4net

The question is actually this; I need info message for every method's start and end. For example I have a code block:

```
    public void MethodName(ObjectName object)
        {
            try
            {
             LOG.Info(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod());

              // Some codes in here
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                LOG.Error(e.Message);
            }
        }
```

I don't want to write **Log.Info** for every method. Any suggestion ?

Comment: By the way, I deleted real code block and object names for security issues. Sorry for that

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38325824/log-method-entry-and-exit-in-net-using-nlog

Comment: I  believe you can find some useful information in this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/171285/logging-entry-and-exit-of-methods-along-with-parameters-automagically

Comment: I saw these posts but there was not an accepted answer there

Comment: @CodeCaster question is not duplicate, I don't want to write any log.info, log.error etc. For example  private static readonly ILog LOG = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType); added beginning of the class, and just using it. I need something like that actually. You missed understand me

Comment: No, you misunderstand the duplicate. The solution is Aspect-Oriented Programming where you rewrite every (or chosen) method to include a pre and post log statement.

Comment: Okay then, I thank you for your explanations. I am trying to do https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25803/how-do-i-intercept-a-method-call-in-c